# inline constexpr function definition legal or not? gcc (ok) vs clang (error)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, language-lawyer

My current program is rejected by clang but compiles fine with gcc. It boils down to the following simplified example:

```
struct A {
  static constexpr inline int one();
};

inline constexpr int A::one() { return 1; }

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

g++ 4.7.2 compiles it without errors (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -o main example.cpp`). clang++ 3.1 rejects it:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -o main example.cpp 
example.cpp:6:25: error: conflicting types for 'one'
inline constexpr int A::one() { return 1; }
                        ^
example.cpp:3:31: note: previous declaration is here
  static constexpr inline int one();
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

My bet is that gcc is right and and clang is wrong? The program should be legal C++11.

Interesting sidenote. If `one` is implemented within the struct, clang no longer complains:

```
struct A {
  static constexpr inline int one() { return 1; }
}
```

gcc also accepts this variant. From my understanding, both versions should be identical according to the standard. Is it a clang bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, note that `constexpr functions and constexpr constructors are implicitly inline`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Removing inline doesn't change anything, though. clang still fails with the same error (conflicting types).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the standard doesn't explicitly mention whether the definition of a `constexpr` static member function is allowed to be separate from its declaration, it has the following example of a separate definition of a `constexpr` constructor, under 7.1.5p1:

```
struct pixel {
  int x;
  int y;
  constexpr pixel(int); // OK: declaration
};
constexpr pixel::pixel(int a)
  : x(square(a)), y(square(a)) // OK: definition
  { }
```

So it seems clear that `constexpr` functions can have separate declaration and definition.  Also in 7.1.5p1:

> If any declaration of a
>   function or function template has `constexpr` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the `constexpr`
>   specifier.

This implies that a `constexpr` function can have (multiple) non-definition declarations.

Answer (score 10):

This was a Clang bug (fixed in Clang 3.2). The problem was that Clang wasn't correctly handling the impact of implicit `const`ness when determining whether a redeclaration of a function matched a prior declaration. Consider:

```
struct A {
  int f();                  // #1
  constexpr int f() const;  // #2 (const is implicit in C++11 and can be omitted)
  static constexpr int g(); // #3
};

int A::f() { return 1; }           // #4, matches #1
constexpr int A::f() { return 1; } // #5, matches #2, implicitly const
constexpr int A::g() { return 1; } // #6, matches #3, not implicitly const
```

When matching the out-of-class declaration #5 against members of `A`, the compiler has a problem: it doesn't know what type the new declaration of `A::f` has yet. If `A::f` is a non-static member function, then its type is `int () const`, and if it's a static member function then its type is `int ()` (no implicit `const`).

Clang 3.1 didn't get this entirely right: it assumed that if a `constexpr` function were a member function then the `constexpr` made it implicitly `const`, which allows #4 and #5 to work, but breaks #6. Clang 3.2 fixes this by implementing the `constexpr`-implies-`const` rule twice: once in redeclaration matching (such that #5 is considered to redeclare #2 and not #1, even though it isn't yet implicitly `const`), and again once the prior declaration has been chosen (to add the implicit const to #5).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that g++ is correct.  In fact this used to be a [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43947) in g++.  I can't find a place in the standard that explicitly says that you can have a static constexpr declaration separate from the definition, but if you look in section 7.1.5 that talks about the constexpr specifier ([summarized here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)), it doesn't rule it out, which generally means that it is allowed.